# How to hyperlink content from archive page with custom post-type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, custom-post-type-archives

I created a custom post type to show my products. The taxonomy name is called field.
My products page (products.php) is customized as the following:

```
<div id="products_wrapper">
    <?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type'=>'product', // Your post type name
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'paged' => $paged,
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-inner">
                    <div class="thumbnail_box">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="permalink_image">
                            <div class="box_thumbnail" style="background-image: url(<?php echo sunset_get_attachment(); ?>);"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="title_excerpt">
                            <div class="title_box">                                 
                            <?php                                    
                            $terms_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'field');                                        
                            $i = 0;                                     
                            foreach($terms_list as $term){ $i++;                                            
                            if($i > 1){                                             
                            echo ', ';                                          }                                           
                            ?><span class="<?php echo $term->name ?> font-icon"></span><?php                                        
                            }                                   
                            ?>
                                <h4 class="product_title">                                      
                                <?php the_title(); ?>                                   
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <p class="category_excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>                            
                        </div>
                        <div class="box_buttons flex">
                            <a class="category_title" href="/field/<?php echo $term->name ?>">
                                <?php
                                 $terms_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'field');
                                    $i = 0;
                                    foreach($terms_list as $term){ $i++;
                                        if($i > 1){
                                            echo ', ';
                                        }
                                        echo $term->name. ' ';
                                    }
                                 ?>
                            </a>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read_more">
                                Learn More
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

           <?php endwhile;
            $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
```

For each product I have a read more that leads to the single products file and the category name shown.
When I click on a category name it leads to the taxonomy page that I created which looks like this:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>    
    <?php
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<div class="box">';
        the_post_thumbnail();
        the_title();
        the_excerpt();
        echo '<a href="http://www.parilinx.burnnotice.co.za/product/<?php the_title() ?>" class="read_more">';
        echo 'Learn More';  
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    endwhile;
    the_posts_navigation();
else :
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
endif; 
?>
```

But now the problem in the category page is that I am not being able to hyperlink the read more button.

Every time I click on the read more it should lead me back to the single product page but it does not.

I first tried to use just: " class="read_more"> but it does not work.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Have you considered using `archive-products.php` and the standard products CPT archive at /products/ rather than recreating it with a page template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `the_permalink` or `get_the_permalink` to display/retrieve the URL of a post ( a post of any type, they're all the same internally )

e.g.

```
the_permalink();
```

orx

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink( $post_id ) ); ?>">
```

Notice I used `esc_url` to escape the value for security reasons.

Here are some similar functions you might find useful:

- `get_post_type_archive_link('product')` should return `/product/` or the equivalent archive for that post type that WP generates
- `get_term_link( 'purple', 'colours')` fetches the archive link for posts that have the term `purple` in the custom taxonomy `colours`. Note that this can also be used for tags and categories. The functions such as tag_link etc all use this function inside them so cut out the middle man!
- `get_author_posts_url(1)` gets the URL of the author posts archive for the user with ID 1
- `get_day_link( $year, $month, $day )` gets the link to a date archive by day
- `get_month_link`, `get_year_link`, same as above
- `get_comment_link( $comment )`, get the permalink to a comment

Note that all of these should be escaped with `esc_url` at the moment of output, with the exception of `the_permalink` which escapes internally

Comment: I've seen this before, but are there any circumstances under which get_permalink would be something that needs to be escaped?

Comment: I used the second option and it works just perfect. Appreciate the support

Comment: @JacobPeattie I always escape `get_permalink`, the convention in core is that if it starts with `get_` it needs escaping. This is because when you escape you always do it at the moment of output. If the `get_` functions escaped then you'd end up double escaping which can be dangerous, so they pass that responsibility on to you. `the_` style functions however output internally, and so they have to be responsible for their own escaping. If in doubt escape, and **never rely on trust**